# Select nodes AND/OR

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Is there any way to select nodes from an XML where 
@id_user=list of ids and 
@id_user!=list of ids?

For selecting 1 id I used this code:

```
Set NODEStoSeparate = ROOT.SelectNodes(facturic[@id_user=35038583])
Set NODEStoKeep = ROOT.SelectNodes(facturic[@id_user!=35038583])
```

Do you guys know of a way to select nodes by multiple IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this link:
http://analystcave.com/vba-xml-working-xml-files/

Not sure if this answers your question exactly...If you have SQL server express (or any other edition), AND you have a big XML file, it would be better to import the data into SQL and use your VBA to query the xml file in SQL using xpath or something similar. It will be much faster. If this is a one time thing, or your xml file is small, this approach may be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to create an interface that others will use, so XPATH works. It seems i need to use | -                                     facturic[@id_user=35038583] | facturic[@id_user=35038583]